# How do you tell if your story subplot is generic, and what can you do to prevent it from happening?

Tags: creative-writing, story

How do you tell if your story subplot is generic, and what can you do to prevent it from happening? I was watching some show and people were commenting how generic the story is and thus the writing was terrible and so on and so forth, so I was wondering if there was a way to determine if this was the case or not. There were so many stories written that I feel you could say that nothing is new under the sun and everything could be labelled as generic, but my question is rather how to tell if your story will be labelled or considered as generic by the majority of people.

The subplot was about a secondary protagonist being extremely powerful and approaching an evil character who's far less powerful than that character and then the powerful character underestimating the far less powerful character and then losing control and falling to his mercy momentarily before regaining control of herself.

To me, it doesn't sound that generic, and I fail to see what could have been done or written differently to change the subplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brainstorm up new, fresh and unexpected details

As you say everything can become generic. Every story has already been told and the only way to create a new story is to add something new, fresh, unexpected, and original.

Otherwise, people will feel they've already read that story and some or all of their enjoyment will be lost. They might think (correctly or not) that you've not gone all-in, and wonders why they should give you their time if you've not given them yours.

To take something that risks becoming too generic (or for that matter any writing) and make it less generic, make a habit of brainstorming alternatives with regards to details of what happens in the plot, who is involved, and what the result of it is, and any other details about the plot you can come up with (place, time, etc).

In fact, you can do this whenever there's a fork in the story where it can go different ways. Brainstorm ideas for where the story can go.

Make lists. Make lists with ten alternatives. You'll probably get stuck around 5 items, but force yourself to keep going. Slam your head to the wall (figuratively speaking! ;o) until you get ten alternatives.

Make each new alternative a bit/a lot more crazy, original, and "out there" than the previous. There's always time to go back and remove the things that don't work later. When brainstorming censor nothing.

Make more than one list. Make so many you'll hate lists...

Maybe you need to involve aliens, Men in Black, giant squids, and steam-powered F1 cars. Maybe you need to disregard many of those ideas. Maybe you need to get them out of your system before you get to the real gems. Maybe only a single one of the alternatives is what clicks with the plot and makes it like no other plot ever.

If you can find one or two changes to a generic plot that makes it unique and interesting the better. You still want people to recognize what's going on, so making everything crazy and original may break the story... unless you're writing the next Alice in Wonderland, perhaps...

When you go beyond the obvious you'll risk becoming silly, but in that silliness, there could be something uniquely original and brilliant.

I think, unless it feels a bit scary to put the text out there, because you've given a bit more of yourself than you feel comfortable with or because you're a bit more original than you feel safe with, unless you have these qualms about the text, it might not be an all-in effort and the reader might feel that.

Baring your soul and risking being silly is probably part of the game if you don't want to be safe, predictable, and generic...